# cant install detox-cli

Tags: react-native, detox

-After installing detox-cli globally, I am trying to run detox -h and I got
**detox is not installed in this directory**.
Unfurtantlly I don't know what to do from here ): 
I have been checked and detox-cli was installd.

thank you

Comment: are you using windows/mac/linux? try to restart the terminal/windows command line (close all windows) how did you install the detox-cli?

Comment: I am using mac.
I installed it like it says's in the Introduction.GettingStarted.md npm install -g detox-cli .
And then for verify it works I type in terminal detox -h
and i got detox is not installed in this directory

Comment: "detox is not installed in this directory. "
cd into your RN directory

Comment: thanks, it's work, but I wonder if it's installed globally so why I cant run this from elsewhere?

Comment: its looking for a project to execute

Comment: ok, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the detox cli in a directory where detox is installed, so in the project you are planning on using detox in. Otherwise it won't do anything, not even show you a help page.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are using the right version of node.

If you have more than one version of node installed, you can deduct the the version from the output when you install detox-cli (e.g. `/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/bin/detox` which is visible when executing `npm i detox --save-dev`) and compare it with the version of node that you are currently using (`node -v`).

You can change to a specific installed version (e.g. 10.17.0) with `nvm use 10.17.0`.